# Force Samsung s7 to bypass Pattern Lock and use Pin

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s7

My daughter has forgotten her pattern lock.  She knows her PIN but it's not giving her that option, only the pattern lock screen.

Is there a way to get access to the PIN lock screen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first answer is 'No' as one can use only one type of screen passcode and you are using 'Pattern Lock' so it replaces your 'PIN lock' which you enabled last time.

> As I'm not sure of security settings of your device, i am assuming it that it may have previous facility from back days devices that uses first 'PIN'/'PASSWORD' and then additional is 'LOCK PATTERN'.
>   If this is the case, try to draw wrong pattern 5 times if PIN is enabled as secondry passcode it would ask you to put your 'PIN'.

Last option would be factory reset your device as it will remove all the current locks.

**How to factory reset s7 ?**

1. Turn off your device.
2. Press and hold the Volume Up and Home buttons.
3. While continuing to hold volume up and home, press and hold the Power button until RECOVERY BOOTING appears in the upper-left then release all buttons.
4. Select Wipe data/factory reset option on screen by using your volume +/- key and power button to click option.
5. Confirm by pressing power button for 'Yes'.
6. Wait, let the system reset finish.
7. Now choose 'Reboot'.

Remember: Your device can ask for you to sign in with owner's google account(the account previously signed in before resetting device) as a [FRP feature](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/frp/).
So make sure you have credentials of your google account.